# In R, how could I loop through columns in a table and perform calculations based on the column name?

Tags: r, loops

I'm loading a table like this:

```
mydata <- read.table("c:\\file.tab", header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote="\"")
```

I can calculate the percentage of blank entries in the COLUMN1_NAME column like so:

```
sum(mydata$COLUMN1_NAME == "")/nrow(mydata)
```

But I have a lot of columns. I'd like a way to loop throw and calculate this percentage for each column instead of copying and pasting the above line and manually changing the column name. I'm pretty new to **R**, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the square brackets with a number rather than a name.

```
i <- 1

sum(sum(mydata[[i]] == "")/nrow(mydata)
```

Etc.

See `?Extract`. Also you could get the names programmatically and work with those, but it's just an extra step:

```
i <- 1
nms <- names(mydata)
sum(mydata[[nms[i]]] == "")/nrow(mydata)
```

Comment: you may also want to consider `%in%` instead of `==` as it's more extendable into matching against a vector.